# Use Multiprocessing and BeautifulSoup to do web scraping, have the MaybeEncodingError and RecursionError

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I am working on a web scraping project. The first dropdown menu has about 800 options and the second dropdown menu has over 20 values. The process of doing it is very slow. So I tried to use multiprocessing in the hope that it could accelerate the process a little bit. However, I got the error messages I couldn't solve.

My codes are:

```
def create_df(city_var, year_var):
    city = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[id*='Main_csCity_ddlEntity1']"))
    city.select_by_visible_text(city_var) 
    year = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[id*='Main_csCity_ddlYear1']"))
    year.select_by_visible_text(year_var) 
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]').click()
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]').click()
        print('something wrong:'+city_var+year_var)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    try:
        small_header = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"ResultsHeader"})
        ret_list = []
        for idx, span in enumerate(small_header[0].find_all("span")):
            if idx in [1,3,5,7]:
                ret_list.append(span.contents[0])
    except:
        print(city_var+year_var)
    try:
        second_header = soup.find_all("tr",{"class":re.compile('Detail.*')})
        ret_list2 = []
        for idx, content in enumerate(second_header):
            if len(content.contents) == 3:
                ret_list2.append([content.contents[1].contents[0], '', '', ''])
            elif len(content.contents) == 7:
                sublist = []
                for idx2 in range(5):
                    if idx2 == 1:
                        continue
                    sublist.append(content.contents[idx2+1].contents[0])
                ret_list2.append(sublist)
            else:
                print('WRONG')
    except:
        print(city_var+year_var)
    ret_list3 = ret_list2[1:]
    ret_list4 = [ret_list+sub for sub in ret_list3]
    return pd.DataFrame(ret_list4)
list_of_city_year = [[x,y] for x in cities1 for y in years]
def return_df(list1):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    c = list1[0]
    y = list1[1]
    df = df.append(create_df(c, y))
    return df
with Pool(5) as p:
    records = p.map(return_df, list_of_city_year[:100])
```

The error message is pretty long. It outputs the previous results as well, so I only put the error part:

> MaybeEncodingError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 with Pool(5) as p:
>   ----> 2     records = p.map(return_df, list_of_city_year[:100])
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func,
>   iterable, chunksize)
>       264         in a list that is returned.
>       265         '''
>   --> 266         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
>       267 
>       268     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self,
>   timeout)
>       642             return self._value
>       643         else:
>   --> 644             raise self._value
>       645 
>       646     def _set(self, i, obj):
>
> MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[      0       1     2
>   3                                    4           5  \ ..... .....
>   ....]'. Reason: 'RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded
>   while calling a Python object',)'

If you have any suggestion on how to improve the code to make it more efficient, please post it below.

Answer (score 0):

such a `MaybeEncodingError` mostly due to this fact that you forgot to use `if __name__ == '__main__':`
when trying to create a working version on Windows, I had a strange repeating error message.

```
Attempt to start a new process before the current process
has finished its bootstrapping phase.

This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:
```

`if __name__ == '__main__':`
literally quoting the comment I got, since it's self-explanatory:

> the error on windows is because each process spawns a new python process which interprets the python file etc. so everything outside the "if main block" is executed again"

so to be portable, you have to use `if __name__=='__main__'` when running this module:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support


if __name__ == '__main__':  #you need this in windows
    freeze_support() 
    main()
```